# unable to search token equals *abc

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

let's say I have indexed documents with name like this: 1:abc, 2:*abc, 3:abc def, 4:def *abc, 5: 1abc

I would like to have a search behaving like this:

Search=abc results=1,2,3,4,5
Search=*abc result =2,4

I use a custom analyser defined like this:

```
Add("myAnalyzer", new CustomAnalyzer
        {
          Tokenizer = "myTokenizer",
          Filter = new[]
          {
            "myAsciiFolding"
            ,"lowercase"
            ,"ipPattern"
          }
        }
```

with tokenizer defined like this:

```
Add("ipTokenizer", new PatternTokenizer
              {
                Pattern = @"\W+"
              })
```

And AsciiFolding like this:

```
Add("ipAsciiFolding", new AsciiFoldingTokenFilter
            {
              PreserveOriginal = true
            })
```

Actually Search 1 succeed but the second (with '*') returns the same as first. Is there a way to specify multiple tokenizer to do what I expected ?

any idea ?

Thx,

Comment: What analyzer are you using in your mapping?  It looks like you might need to switch to the [Whitespace analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) if you want to treat * as data and not be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

to do this:

> Search=abc results=1,2,3,4,5 Search=*abc result =2,4

as you're searching within a string (look for "abc" inside "*abc") and you wouldn't want  a search for "*abc" to match against "*def abc", I would use [nGrams](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) to tokenise the data.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test' -d '
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_ngram_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "my_ngram_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer" : {
                "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                    "type" : "nGram",
                    "min_gram" : "2",
                    "max_gram" : "5",
                    "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit", "punctuation", "symbol" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

if your terms (*abc etc.) are all 5 chars or less then I would use a [term](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) query (i.e. you'll find an exactly matching term in the index.

if your terms are longer than 5 chars I would use a [query_string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) and set the **default_operator** to be AND